# Node.js, Express, Jade - Separate layout files

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm working on some project with Node.js, Express and Jade, where I'd like to seperate layout files. Inside the main file is already separated header, but I don't know how to do this for sublayout where I need to pass data. In this case I need to pass data to widgets for every view on page, but in the route would be too many things to load data into widgets instead of some easy solution which I'm looking for.

I could do this thing on the way which I described above - to load data in view with every request, but this is somehow time & cpu consuming.
Another way I'm thinking of is to create some sublayout for widgets in which I'd load data once and then would be available all the time without calling data from DB in all requests. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I work with *mustache* but I think you can use a similar strategy that I do.In most of the mustache templates that I use there is a common header and footer section.Along with the scripts and css files.I have created a separate partials file that *exports* these partials 
.For instance my partial file looks like this.

```
exports.partials = function (isAuthenticated)
{
    var menu;

    isAuthenticated ?
     menu = {
         header: '',
         footer: ' '
     } :
    menu = {
        header: '',
        footer: ''
    }
    return menu;
};
exports.staticResources = {
     bootstrap :'//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css',
     fonts : '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0/css/font-awesome.css',
     jquery : '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'        
};
```

I have another method called generatePartials which as the name suggest generate the partials for my templates

```
exports.generatePartials = function(isAuthenticated){   
var menu = resources.partials(isAuthenticated);
var partials = {
    header : menu.header,
    footer : menu.footer,
    bootstrap : resources.staticResources.bootstrap,
    fonts :resources.staticResources.fonts,
    jquery :resources.staticResources.jquery,
};
return partials;
};
```

Now while rendering the template all I have to do is this

```
app.get('/routeName',function (req, res){
var partials = require('../helpers').generatePartials(req.isAuthenticated());
return res.render('viewName.html', partials);
};
```

And that's it.